# Even density function, distribution - just checking if my solution is correctW

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

We are given $f_X$ - density function of a random variable $X$, it is an even function, that is $f_X(t) = f_X(-t), \ t \in \mathbb{R}$

$F_X$ is the distribution function for $X$

Prove that $F_X (t) + F_X(-t) = 1$

This is how I do it:

$$F_X (x) = \int_{- \infty}^x f(t)dt, \ \ \ F_X (-x) = \int_{- \infty}^{-x} f(t)dt = |t=-s, dt = -ds| = -\int_{\infty}^{x} f(-s)ds = \int^{\infty}_{x} f(-s)ds =  \int^{\infty}_{x} f(s)ds$$

So, suming up, $F_X (x) + F_X(-x) =  \int_{- \infty}^x f(t)dt + \int^{\infty}_{x} f(s)ds = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)dt = 1$

Is everything ok? Can it be that simple? Did I miss something?

Comment: Of course, I'll correct that. There is a modification of this problem, which  I don't know how to handle. I'll edit my question.

Comment: The solution is now fine. But while I was typing an answer to the question you said you did not know how to do, you deleted that part.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169231/probability-distribution-is-symmetric-at-a-point-distribution-function-fx Yes, I did, I formulated a new question. Thank you a lot and I'm very sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second problem, let $B$ be the event $X\le t$. Then $\Pr(B)=F_X(t)$ and
$$\Pr(B)+\Pr(B^c)=1.$$
Let $A=B^c$. Then $\Pr(A)=\Pr(X\gt t)=\Pr(X\lt -t)$. If we can show that $\Pr(X\lt -t)=\Pr(X\le -t)=F_X(-t)$ we will be finished.

All that is needed is to show that $\Pr(X=-t)=0$.  This follows from the continuity assumption on $F_X$.  For if $\Pr(X=-t)=p\gt 0$, then $\lim_{w\to t^-} F_X(w)=F_X(t)-p\ne F_X(-t)$.