# Probability distribution is symmetric at a point, distribution function $F(x) + F(-x) =1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Show that if the distribution $P_X$ is symmetric at $m \in \mathbb{R}$, and there are no discontinuities of the distribution function, then the distribution function $F_X$ satisfies $F_X(t) + F_X(−t) = 1, t \in \mathbb{R}$

Could you help me with that?

I can show this, straight from the equality: $F_X(t) = P(X \in (- \infty, t ))$, for $m =0$.

How can I generalize it to any real number $m$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F_{X}$ is a continuous CDF then:

$$F_{X}\left(t\right)+F_{X}\left(-t\right)=P\left(X\leq t\right)+1-P\left(X\geq-t\right)$$

So that: $$\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\left[F_{X}\left(t\right)+F_{X}\left(-t\right)=1\right]\iff\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\left[P\left(X\leq t\right)=P\left(X\geq-t\right)\right]\iff X\text{ is symmetric at }0$$

Comment: So we cannot add any assumptions about the probability distribution, so that the statement would be true for $m \neq 0$?

Comment: Why does $F_X(0)= 1/2 = P(X \le 0)$ imply that the statement isn't true for $m \neq 0$? I suppose it has something to do with the fact that the distribution is symmetric but I don't see why that is, exactly.

Comment: If the distribution is symmetric at $m$ then $F(m)=\frac12$. But I must admit: even if $m\neq0$ then that does not exclude $F(0)=\frac12$. I will take away that part. Secondly the statement implies that the distribution is symmetric at $0$. So the answer to the question in your first comment is 'yes'.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$X$ is symmetric so 
$$P\left(X  \leq -m \right) = P\left(X  \geq m \right).$$
Use the equality
$$P\left(X \in (m,\infty)\right) = 1-F_X(m).$$